# Query with integer values Java

Tags: java

I've got a problem with a query in java that includes integer values. The table from which I want to extract data contains 4 columns and it's called "request" : idbook (integer),Date (datetime) Number(integer) and userID(string) In a Java class I wrote the query that takes from another class these 4 parameters in form of String. Now How can I write the query using the INSERT INTO clause?

Comment: please add some code in your question.

Comment: Please visit google before visiting stackoverflow.  If you still reach stackoverflow, show what code you have already tried, explain what the problem is, and ask how it can be fixed.  Stackoverflow is not about getting other people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

This example elaborates the use of Prepared Statement.
This should solve your problem.

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO REQUEST"
    + "(IDBOOK, DATE, NUMBER, USERID) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setDate(2, "<your date time>");
preparedStatement.setInt(3, 4);
preparedStatement.setString(4, "myId");
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Good point. I have included code. Please upvote if you think this is useful.